# Use a plugin defined field inside template

Tags: custom-field

I've created a custom field for my plugin and it's working great, but if I want to use the same field within my `templateDetails.xml` I get an almost blank page in the template style edit page. I should probably mention that my `getInput()` method loads no layout, it simply returns an `<input>` with a bunch of attributes.

Here's my templateDetails.xml part

```
<fieldset name="advanced" label="Some FIELDSET NAME" 
    addfieldpath="/plugins/editors-xtd/myPlugin/models/fields">

    <field 
        name="myFieldName"
        type="myFieldType"
        label="SOME LABEL"
        hint="Some hint"
        description=""
        class=""
        format="HTML"
        default=""
    />
</fieldset>
```

The console says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The page title says:

> Error: 0 Call to undefined function random()

Is there something wrong here or am I missing something with my field?

Comment: just to eliminate possible issues - are you sure this error appears when you include your custom field in your templateDetails.xml? Can you remove it from your xml and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, just did, I removed it and problem goes away, but I need the field there. I found that another field works, except that it doesn't load it's scripts, an easy fix. Going to investigate tomorrow as soon as I open my eyes.

Comment: Whenever you're getting a Joomla error page, enable system debug in Global Configuration to see where it's coming from.

Comment: @Sharky I'm using full debug enabled, perhaps I need to enable `show_error` in `php.ini` once I get to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I want to always use an ID for my fields to make sure they are unique for JavaScript initialization, so I misspelled `rand()` for `random()`, so while all my custom field instances were using an ID in the `templateDetails.xml` file, I couldn't figure out what's going on.