# Joomla 4 template namespace

Tags: templates, custom-field, joomla-4

I'm working with latest Joomla 4 beta, and wondering how can I use namespaces with templates so I can start using and developing custom fields for my templates.

I need to know what should I set in the `templateDetails.xml` file so I can use proper `addfieldprefix` address for my custom fields.

Some context:

- what I have and currently use is based on my previous questions asked here: [plugin defined custom field](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24594/use-a-plugin-defined-field-inside-template) - partially works with `addfieldpath` for templates, [use plugin defined custom field inside another plugin](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24693/access-namespaced-custom-field-method-from-a-plugin-into-another-plugin), [setting extension namespace](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/joomla-4-how-to-set-namespace-for-custom-field-addfieldprefix)
- no matter how/what, using `addfieldprefix` inside the `templateDetails.xml` and linking from a plugin doesn't work; EG `addfieldprefix="Joomla\CMS\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field"`
- I also found no documentation, stackoverflow or any resource about using namespaced custom form fields inside `templateDetails.xml`, I only found the `libraries/namespacemap.php` and seems only 4 types of items can use this system: `if (!in_array($type, ['component', 'module', 'plugin', 'library'], true))`

Open to any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: For those interested, probably mostly @Sharky, I made a [PR](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/30816) to Joomla git in regards to this.